# Find the largest k numbers in k arrays stored across k machines

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is an interview question. I have K machines each of which is connected to 1 central machine. Each of the K machines have an array of 4 byte numbers in file. You can use any data structure to load those numbers into memory on those machines and they fit. Numbers are not unique across K machines. Find the K largest numbers in the union of the numbers across all K machines. What is the fastest I can do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Find the k largest numbers on each machine. O(n*log(k))
- Combine the results (on a centralized server, if k is not huge, otherwise you can merge them in a tree-hierarchy accross the server cluster).

Update: to make it clear, the combine step is not a sort. You just pick the top k numbers from the results. There are many ways to do this efficiently. You can use a heap for example, pushing the head of each list. Then you can remove the head from the heap and push the head from the list the element belonged to. Doing this k times gives you the result. All this is O(k*log(k)).

Comment: combining the results and sorting it would take k^k steps and comparisons again. Please see my answer that solves this. But please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks...

Comment: what if the largest numbers are all in one or a few of the arrays?

Answer (score 12):

(This is an interesting problem because it involves parallelism. As I haven't encountered parallel algorithm optimization before, it's quite amusing: you can get away with some ridiculously high-complexity steps, because you can make up for it later. Anyway, onto the answer...)

> "*What is the fastest I can do this?*"

**The best you can do is O(K).** Below I illustrate both a simple O(K log(K)) algorithm, and the more complex O(K) algorithm.

---

**First step:**

Each computer needs enough time to read every element. This means that *unless the elements are already in memory, one of the two bounds on the time is O(largest array size)*. If for example your largest array size varies as O(K log(K)) or O(K^2) or something, no amount of algorithmic trickery will let you go faster than that. Thus the actual best running time is `O(max(K, largestArraySize))` technically.

Let us say the arrays have a max length of N, which is <=K. With the above caveat, we're allowed to bound `N<K` since each computer has to look at each of its elements at least once (O(N) preprocessing per computer), each computer can pick the largest K elements (this is known as finding kth-order-statistics, see these linear-time [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Selecting_k_smallest_or_largest_elements)). Furthermore, we can do so for free (since it's also O(N)).

---

**Bounds and reasonable expectations:**

Let's begin by thinking of some worst-case scenarios, and estimates for the minimum amount of work necessary.

- One minimum-work-necessary estimate is O(K*N/K) = O(N), because we need to look at every element at the very least. But, if we're smart, we can distribute the work evenly across all K computers (hence the division by K).
- Another minimum-work-necessary estimate is O(N): if one array is larger than all elements on all other computers, we return the set.
- We must output all K elements; this is at least O(K) to print them out. We can avoid this if we are content merely knowing where the elements are, in which case the O(K) bound does not necessarily apply.

Can this bound of O(N) be achieved? Let's see...

---

**Simple approach - O(NlogN + K) = O(KlogK):**

For now let's come up with a simple approach, which achieves O(NlogN + K).

Consider the data arranged like so, where each column is a computer, and each row is a number in the array:

```
computer: A  B  C  D  E  F  G
      10 (o)      (o)          
       9  o (o)         (o)    
       8  o    (o)             
       7  x     x    (x)        
       6  x     x          (x)  
       5     x     ..........     
       4  x  x     ..          
       3  x  x  x  . .          
       2     x  x  .  .        
       1     x  x  .           
       0     x  x  .
```

You can also imagine this as a [sweep-line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) from computation geometry, or an efficient variant of the 'merge' step from mergesort. The elements with parentheses represent the elements with which we'll initialize our potential "candidate solution" (in some central server). The algorithm will converge on the correct `o` responses by dumping the `(x)` answers for the two unselected `o`s.

Algorithm:

- All computers start as 'active'.
- Each computer sorts its elements. (parallel O(N logN))
- Repeat until all computers are inactive:

  - Each active computer finds the next-highest element (O(1) since sorted) and gives it to the central server.
  - The server smartly combines the new elements with the old K elements, and removes an equal number of the lowest elements from the combined set. To perform this step efficiently, we have a global priority queue of fixed size K. We insert the new potentially-better elements, and bad elements fall out of the set. Whenever an element falls out of the set, we tell the computer which sent that element to never send another one. (Justification: *This always raises the smallest element of the candidate set.*)

(sidenote: Adding a callback hook to falling out of a priority queue is an O(1) operation.)

We can see graphically that this will perform at most 2K*(findNextHighest_time + queueInsert_time) operations, and as we do so, elements will naturally fall out of the priority queue. findNextHighest_time is O(1) since we sorted the arrays, so to minimize 2K*queueInsert_time, we choose a priority queue with an O(1) insertion time (e.g. a Fibonacci-heap based priority queue). This gives us an O(log(queue_size)) extraction time (we cannot have O(1) insertion and extraction); however, we never need to use the extract operation! Once we are done, we merely *dump* the priority queue as an unordered set, which takes O(queue_size)=O(K) time.

We'd thus have O(N log(N) + K) total running time (parallel sorting, followed by O(K)*O(1) priority queue insertions). In the worst case of N=K, this is O(K log(K)).

---

**The better approach - O(N+K) = O(K):**

However I have come up with a better approach, which achieves O(K). It is based on the [median-of-median selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm), but parallelized. It goes like this:

**We can eliminate a set of numbers if we know for sure that there are at least K (not strictly) larger numbers somewhere among all the computers.**

Algorithm:

- Each computer finds the `sqrt(N)`th highest element of its set, and splits the set into elements < and > it. This takes O(N) time in parallel.
- The computers collaborate to combine those statistics into a new set, and find the `K/sqrt(N)`th highest element of *that* set (let's call it the 'superstatistic'), and note which computers have statistics < and > the superstatistic. This takes O(K) time.
- Now consider all elements less than their computer's statistics, on computers whose statistic is less than the superstatistic. **Those elements can be eliminated.** This is because the elements greater than their computer's statistic, on computers whose statistic is larger than the superstatistic, are a set of K elements which are larger. (See the visual [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm)).
- Now, the computers with the uneliminated elements evenly redistribute their data to the computers who lost data.
- Recurse: you still have K computers, but the value of N has decreased. Once N is less than a predetermined constant, use the **previous** algorithm I mentioned in "simple approach - O(NlogN + K)"; except in this case, it is now O(K). =)

It turns out that the reductions are O(N) total (amazingly not order K), except perhaps the final step which might by O(K). Thus this algorithm is O(N+K) = **O(K)** total.

Analysis and simulation of O(K) running time below. The statistics allow us to divide the world into four unordered sets, represented here as a rectangle divided into four subboxes:

```
         ------N-----

         N^.5            
         ________________                     
|       |     s          |  <- computer
|       | #=K s  REDIST. |  <- computer
|       |     s          |  <- computer
| K/N^.5|-----S----------|  <- computer
|       |     s          |  <- computer
K       |     s          |  <- computer
|       |     s  ELIMIN. |  <- computer
|       |     s          |  <- computer
|       |     s          |  <- computer
|       |_____s__________|  <- computer

LEGEND:
s=statistic, S=superstatistic
#=K -- set of K largest elements
```

(I'd draw the relation between the unordered sets of rows and s-column here, but it would clutter things up; see the addendum right now quickly.)

For this analysis, we will consider N as it decreases.

At a given step, we are able to eliminate the elements labelled `ELIMIN`; this has removed area from the rectangle representation above, reducing the problem size from K*N to [image], which *hilariously* simplifies to [image]

Now, the computers with the uneliminated elements redistribute their data (`REDIST` rectangle above) to the computers with eliminated elements (`ELIMIN`). This is done in parallel, where the bandwidth bottleneck corresponds to the length of the short size of `REDIST` (because they are outnumbered by the `ELIMIN` computers which are waiting for their data). Therefore the data will take as long to transfer as the long length of the `REDIST` rectangle (another way of thinking about it: `K/√N * (N-√N)` is the area, divided by `K/√N` data-per-time, resulting in O(`N-√N`) time).

Thus at each step of size `N`, we are able to reduce the problem size to `K(2√N-1)`, at the cost of performing `N + 3K + (N-√N)` work. We now recurse. The recurrence relation which will tell us our performance is:

```
T(N) = 2N+3K-√N + T(2√N-1)
```

The decimation of the subproblem size is much faster than the normal geometric series (being √N rather than something like N/2 which you'd normally get from common divide-and-conquers). Unfortunately neither the Master Theorem nor the powerful Akra-Bazzi theorem work, but we can at least convince ourselves it is linear via a simulation:

```
>>> def T(n,k=None):
...      return 1 if n<10 else sqrt(n)*(2*sqrt(n)-1)+3*k+T(2*sqrt(n)-1, k=k)
>>> f = (lambda x: x)
>>> (lambda n: T((10**5)*n,k=(10**5)*n)/f((10**5)*n) - T(n,k=n)/f(n))(10**30)
-3.552713678800501e-15
```

The function `T(N)` is, at large scales, a multiple of the linear function `x`, hence linear (doubling the input doubles the output). This method, therefore, almost certainly achieves the bound of `O(N)` we conjecture. Though see the addendum for an interesting possibility.

---

...

---

*Addendum*

- One pitfall is *accidentally* sorting. If we do anything which accidentally sorts our elements, we will incur a log(N) penalty at the least. *Thus it is better to think of the arrays as sets*, to avoid the pitfall of thinking that they are sorted.
- Also we might initially think that with the constant amount of work at each step of 3K, so we would have to do work 3K*log(log(N)) work. But the -1 has a powerful role to play in the decimation of the problem size. It is very slightly possible that the running time is actually something above linear, but definitely much smaller than even N*log(log(log(log(N)))). For example it might be something like O(N*[InverseAckermann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse)(N)), but I hit the recursion limit when testing.
- The O(K) is probably only due to the fact that we have to print them out; if we are content merely knowing where the data is, we might even be able to pull off an O(N) (e.g. if the arrays are of length O(log(K)) we might be able to achieve O(log(K)))... but that's another story.
- The relation between the unordered sets is as follows. Would have cluttered things up in explanation.

.

```
          _
         / \
(.....) > s > (.....)
          s
(.....) > s > (.....)
          s
(.....) > s > (.....)
         \_/

          v

          S

          v

         / \
(.....) > s > (.....)
          s
(.....) > s > (.....)
          s
(.....) > s > (.....)
         \_/
```

Comment: How come the better solution is O(K) total, won't there be O(K) rounds in the worst case?

Comment: The sorting answer was what I gave. How is your second solution O(k)? Don't you have to find the ith maximum in each of the k arrays k times?

Comment: @svick: Yes, but in that particular case, each round will be O(1) deletion if done properly. I am double-checking my work though (always a good thing), and will update shortly if I find an issue.

Comment: @Aks: thanks for pointing that out. I have edited this into a solution that truly achieves O(K), with the solution you mentioned (actually O(K log(K))) still there as the first solution I mention.

Answer (score 3):

- Maintain a min heap of size 'k' in the centralized server.
- Initially insert first k elements into the min heap.
- For the remaining elements

  - Check(peek) for the min element in the heap (O(1))
  - If the min element is lesser than the current element, then remove the min element from heap and insert the current element.
- Finally min heap will have 'k' largest elements
- This would require n(log k) time.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

- take the k largest numbers on each machine in sorted order O(Nk) where N is the number of element on each machine
- sort each of these arrays of k elements by largest element (you will get k arrays of k elements sorted by largest element : a square matrix kxk)
- take the "upper triangle" of the matrix made of these k arrays of k elements, (the k largest element will be in this upper triangle)
- the central machine can now find  the k largest element of these k(k+1)/2 elements

Comment: what do you mean by "sort each of these arrays of k elements by largest element"?

Comment: you create a matrix from these arrays, (where each column is an array from a machine). Then you sort each of these columns so that the first element of each column are sorted in decreasing order (i.e the first line of the matrix is sorted) . It's pretty much like combining the arrays, but you get to look at only half of the combined elements to find the k largest.

Comment: But what if one of the arrays is all K largest elements. The upper triangle wont cover it?

Comment: yes it would, if one array contains all the K largest elements, then it must be the first one in the sorted list of arrays, and therefore it's in the upper (LEFT) triangle of the matrix.

Comment: It would be easier to explain with a drawing of the matrix :D .

Answer (score 1):

1. Let the machines find the out k largest elements copy it into a
   datastructure (stack), sort it and pass it on to the Central
   machine.
2. At the central machine receive the stacks from all the machine. Find
   the greatest of the elements at the top of the stacks.
3. Pop out the greatest element form its stack and copy it to the **'TopK list'**. 
   Leave the other stacks intact.
4. Repeat **step 3**, k times to get Top K numbers.

Answer (score 0):

1) sort the items on every machine 
2) use a k - binary heap on the central machine 
a) populate the heap with first (max) element from each machine 
b) extract the first element, and put back in the heap the first element from the machine that you extracted the element. (of course heapify your heap, after the element is added).

Sort will be O(N*log(N)) where N is the max array on the machines. 
O(k) - to build the heap
O(k*log(k)) to extract and populate the heap k times.

Complexity is max(O(k*log(k)),O(N*log(N)))

Answer (score -1):

I would think the MapReduce paradigm would be well suited to a task like this.

Every machine runs it's own independent map task to find the maximum value in its array (depends on the language used) and this will probably be O(N) complexity for N numbers on each machine.

The reduce task compares the result from the individual machines' outputs to give you the largest k numbers.

Comment: The problem is that the largest K numbers might all be on the same machine.  You'll underestimate the max in that case.

Comment: In which case MapReduce would still run in the same manner on one machine. I've implemented similar problems on Hadoop. It works as well for 1 or k machines.

Comment: Google pays me lots of money to write mapreduces, but that is mostly irrelevant.  Consider A = {-1, 0}, B = {1, 2}, Map(A) -> 0, Map(B) -> 2, Reduce({Map(A), Map(B)} = {0, 2}.  Max2({-1, 0, 1, 2}) = {1, 2}.  For your solution to work, you need to send all of the data to the reducer, which is not very efficient/distributed.

Comment: Ah alright. I see your point. Thanks for that. Out of academic interest, how different is this compared to the approach suggested by Karoly which suggests calculating the max at each machine and deciding the overall max at the central machine?

Comment: @ne0lithic_coder Because you are picking the k largest elements in each machine, you won't be missing any of the largest elements