# How to efficiently find top-k elements?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, tf-idf

I have a big sequence file storing the tfidf values for documents. Each line represents line and the columns are the value of tfidfs for each term (the row is a sparse vector). I'd like to pick the top-k words for each document using Hadoop. The naive solution is to loop through all the columns for each row in the mapper and pick the top-k but as the file becomes bigger and bigger I don't think this is a good solution. Is there a better way to do that in Hadoop?

Comment: Interesting question. Upvoted. Well see if the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872099/find-the-largest-k-numbers-in-k-arrays-stored-across-k-machines can be used to get top-k numbers and further you may get the words from some {colID -> word} representation you used to create tfidf vectors.

Comment: If it works, you may add an answer to this question yourself.

Comment: can u give example of the data

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. In every map calculate TopK (this is local top K for each map)
 2. Spawn a signle reduce , now top K from all mappers will flow to this reducer and hence global Top K will be evaluated.
```

Think of the problem as

```
 1. You have been given the results of X number of horse races. 
 2. You need to find Top N fastest horse.
```