# N largest elements of a vector along with their indices

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust, gpu, reduction

I have a `thrust::device_vector <float> vec`. Assume that `vec.size() = L` and that `N < L`. I want to find the largest `N` elements in `vec` along with their indices. How can we do this efficiently using raw CUDA or `thrust`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to first sort the values and then select the last `N` elements.

The following example selects the `N=5` largest elements and their original indices from `L=18` values.

**compile using**

`nvcc -std=c++11 nlargest.cu -o nlargest`

---

**output when running ./nlargest**

```
d_values:   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1   2   
d_indices:  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  
d_values:   0   1   1   2   2   3   4   4   5   5   6   6   7   7   8   8   9   9   
d_indices:  15  0   16  1   17  2   3   9   4   10  5   11  6   12  7   13  8   14  
d_values_s: 7   8   8   9   9   
d_indices_s:12  7   13  8   14
```

---

**nlargest.cu**

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <iostream>

#define PRINTER(name) print(#name, (name))
template <template <typename...> class V, typename T, typename ...Args>
void print(const char* name, const V<T,Args...> & v)
{
    std::cout << name << ":\t";
    thrust::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\t"));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<typename... Iterators>
__host__ __device__
thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<Iterators...>> zip(Iterators... its)
{
    return thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(its...));
}


int main()
{

    const int size = 18;
    const int select_size = 5;

    float values[size] = {1,2,3,
                          4,5,6,
                          7,8,9,
                          4,5,6,
                          7,8,9,
                          0,1,2
    };

    thrust::host_vector<float> h_values (values, values+size);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_values = h_values;
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_indices(size);
    thrust::sequence(d_indices.begin(), d_indices.end());

    PRINTER(d_values);
    PRINTER(d_indices);
    thrust::sort(zip(d_values.begin(), d_indices.begin()),zip(d_values.end(), d_indices.end()));
    PRINTER(d_values);
    PRINTER(d_indices);

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_values_s(select_size);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_indices_s(select_size);

    thrust::copy(zip(d_values.end()-select_size, d_indices.end()-select_size),
                zip(d_values.end(), d_indices.end()),
                zip(d_values_s.begin(), d_indices_s.begin())
                );
    PRINTER(d_values_s);
    PRINTER(d_indices_s);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872099/find-the-largest-k-numbers-in-k-arrays-stored-across-k-machines)

I like Ricky Bobby's answer (if N is much smaller than L).

I also suggest looking at the following paper.
[Fast K-selection Algorithm for Graphics Processing Units](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2345676)
by Alabi T et al.

It provides 3 different parallel algorithms for K-selection.
The bucket-select they describe performed best.
The algorithm has two steps:

Step 1 (pre-processing to split the original data into vectors of size less than 2^21 elements)

Step 2:

```
1. Choose bucket containing Kth element
2. split the bucket again.
3. Repeat until the kth element is found (the min and max of the new bucket are equal).
```

Now you'll already have the other k-1 greatest elements partitioned into buckets.

This method is also referred to as distributive partitioning.

Comment: Link is dead, please replace

Comment: @opa I replaced the link but could no longer find a link to the direct paper only to it's download page from ACM.

Comment: I had to wayback machine it